# Parsing price changes for products on MariaDB and saving differences to product table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm creating a MariaDB database that is parsing a set of products and prices daily. A Python script goes through the API, gets any new products and adds them to the products table, afterwards it scans all prices and saves to the price table with the product code and timestamp.

I'm trying to add percentage differences to the products table for the last 7, 30 and 60 days using SQL because I believe that would be faster than iterating using Python.

Here's a peak at the products table:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
| prod_code | prod_name                                     | date_added |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
| 22207     | Casa Burmester Reserva D.O.C. Douro Branco    | 2019-10-20 |
| 16879     | Durbanville Hills First Fill New Oak          | 2019-10-20 |
| 22141     | Miguel Torres Gran Reserva Cabernet Sauvignon | 2019-10-20 |
| 18028     | Chateau Langlet A.O.C. Graves Blanc           | 2019-10-20 |
| 16774     | Teorema D.O. Calatayud Garnacha               | 2019-10-20 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

And this is the prices table for `prod_code = '22141'`:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
| id    | prod_code | price | timestamp           |
+-------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
| 10636 | 22141     | 60.71 | 2019-10-29 09:07:38 |
|  9798 | 22141     | 60.71 | 2019-10-28 09:07:58 |
|  8961 | 22141     | 62.05 | 2019-10-27 09:07:18 |
|  8111 | 22141     | 62.05 | 2019-10-26 09:08:10 |
|  7253 | 22141     | 62.05 | 2019-10-25 09:07:22 |
|  6436 | 22141     | 62.05 | 2019-10-24 09:09:18 |
|  5597 | 22141     | 62.05 | 2019-10-23 09:08:53 |
|  4410 | 22141     | 74.06 | 2019-10-21 09:09:03 |
|  3561 | 22141     | 89.93 | 2019-10-20 00:09:15 |
+-------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
```

My intent is to get the minimum price in the last 7 days divided by the mode of the last 7 days. I was able to do that through this query I've built:

```
SELECT ROUND(
    SUM((
        (SELECT MIN(price) AS divisor
         FROM prices WHERE prod_code ='22141'
         AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
         ORDER BY price DESC) /
        (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE prod_code ='22141'
         AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
         GROUP BY price
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1))
        * 100),2) AS percentage
```

In this example, it gives me `97.84` which tells me that there's been a day in the last 7 days where the price was 97.84% of the mode price.

The good side is that I've got the query going for me. The question now is: I'd like to add a new column to the products table named, 7_days_mode and I'd do this calculation for every single product_code. Is there a way to do this in MariaDB, in a "programmable" or automated SQL way when new price values come in, or will I be better off kicking out another Python script and iterate through the whole thing once my script that gets data from the API is done?

(I'm also taking suggestions on making the calculations faster, if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `VIEW` over the `products` table, including the calculation for the `7_day_mode`:

```
CREATE VIEW products_mode AS
SELECT *,
       ROUND((SELECT price
              FROM prices 
              WHERE prod_code = products.prod_code
                AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
              GROUP BY price
              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1), 2) AS 7_day_mode
FROM products
```

Then you can simply

```
SELECT *
FROM products_mode
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cd47a9bbadaf721a19dceff8efd28ebf)

Comment: Wow, so simple and so elegant. Never thought of adding a calculation into a view. Thank you very much!